# Htaccess if url starts with

Tags: .htaccess

So I am no hero when it comes to htaccess. So forgive me if I have the complete wrong code below.

Here are the example links (behind each link a number to which I shall refrer bellow to which htaccess part they should be linking to):

```
website.com/home/  #1
website.com/home/page2/  #1
website.com/projects/  #1 or #2 (doesnt matter since the first GET will be page in both cases)
website.com/projects/staticpage/  #1
website.com/projects/filter1/  #2
website.com/projects/filter1/filter2/  #2
```

The current code I am using is **(part 1)**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/projects/$
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2&sub-sub=$3  [L,QSA]
```

The other bit of the htaccess **(part 2)**:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/?$ index.php?secondpart=$1  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/?$ index.php?secondpart=$1&filter[]=$2  [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/?$ index.php?secondpart=$1&filter[]=$2&filter[]=$3  [L,QSA]
```

*The filters are dynamic so it is not possible to get them to exclude.* 
 
I get it to skip the first part when the url is equal to: **website.com/projects/** but,
when I change the url to: **website.com/projects/filter1/** I can't get it to grab the second part.

If you could help me fix this thank you very much.

Comment: Like anubhava said it would not have been possible what I was trying to do. 

I solved the problem by fixing it by doing a php check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/pagesearch/(staticpage1|staticpage2)/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Changed my question to give you a better explanation.

Comment: Now this question has become unclear to me. Provide your complete .htaccess in location and clarify what you need. It appears to me that you want to handle same pattern `^/?([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/([-A-Za-z0-9-_+]+)/?$` differently in same .htaccess which is not possible.